# HTML writing position

Tags: html, css

This is an HTML, I need to add both the CSS and HTML in 1 HTML file,
but when I add this CSS in the HTML as the rest it gets ruined, any
idea where I should put the CSS comment (margin) without ruining the
shape of my HTML, I am sorry I am beginner:

```css
.advertise img {
  margin: 75px 0 371px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="display: flex;
   gap: 25px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   float: right;  
   list-style-type:none;" class="Header">
   <style>
      a {
      text-align: left;
      opacity: 0.75;
      font-family: Roboto, 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 3;
      color: #f2f1f2;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style-type: none;
      height: 29.9px;
      position: relative;
      left: -420px;
      }
   </style>
   <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#BestSeller">Best Seller</a></li>
   <li><a href="#NewInstructor">New Instructor</a></li>
   <li><a href="#Instructor">Instructor</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="image">
   <img style="width: 250px;
      height: 100%px;
      margin-top: -100px;
      margin-left: 550px" src="https://about.almentor.net/assets/images/alm-logo.png" alt="Almentor" class="logo">
</div>
<section class="advertise">
   <div class="advertise">
      <img style="width: 800px;
         height: 400px;
         opacity: 0.7;
         background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.14), #000);
         " src="https://github.com/Monica1906/e-commerce/blob/main/%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81_%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%85_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%83.jpg?raw=true" alt="Almentor" class="bigPic">
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I've updated the question to a runnable code snippet.  Can you indicate specifically what isn't working as expected?  *"as the rest it gets ruined"* doesn't really describe the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add all your style in the header, like this your CSS style will load first and the rest of your page will load properly.
Another good practice is to have all the javascript at the end *(to load first the visual and then the javascript actions)*

And what do you want to do exactly with your CSS? You can use CodePen to share us the code and it will give a display of the noted HTML/CSS. It might be easier to see what's going wrong.

*Thanks David for the code snippet!*

Comment: https://codepen.io/monica-mamdouh/pen/PoeOpVm, this is my code pen, i am just doing HTML and CSS for now I need to move the last CSS into the HTML, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hey, if you need further information from the person asking the question, please comment on it instead of posting the answer.